# jQuery Form, ajaxForm(), does not process radio button in IE when its set by Javascript

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, dialog, ajaxform

I set a radio button from data returned by Google Map, like so:

```
countryCode = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
$('input[type=radio][name=country]').prop('checked', false);
$('input:radio[name=country]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === countryCode) {
        $('#' + countryCode).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

This sets a country abbreviation, e.g., US as the value of a radio button. The HTML for the radios look like (there are several):

```
<label><input type="radio" id="US"  name="country" form="dataInput" value="US" />United States</label>
```

After user input of other data, the submit fires jQuery's Form plug-in. I'm using version 3.46-2013.11.21  The command is:

```
$('#dataInput').ajaxForm( submitOptions );
```

The submitOptions object contains parameters. An alert right before this line shows that the country radio button still has the proper data.

The PHP picks up the data with the following statement:

```
$country = $_POST['country']; //for IE, PHP says Notice: undefined index: country
```

And with IE, generates a validation error back to the user who has entered correct data.

All the above works in Firefox and Chrome, in many versions. It does not work in IE 8 through 11. When the HTML is changed, as a test, to include checked="checked", IE 11 picks up the country, but it then does not pick up the next input, the state. Firefox and Chrome are OK. As the last bit of this long running mystery (for me, anyway) is that several other radio buttons for other things, set by checked="checked" in the HTML work fine in all IE versions tested.

How do I get the country radio button, set via Javascript, to pass through to the PHP server in an IE browser? I've worked many hours on this. Please be specific. I can provide more info, if necessary.

Comment: It would seem to me that the data is getting lost or removed by the form plugin as I have several forms with jQuery-selected radio buttons and those get passed to my PHP scripts just fine. I am using $.post() and /or $.ajax()

Comment: Yes, Jay, but the Form plug-in passes other radio buttons right through. Form uses $.ajax(). I want to stay with Form because it easily handles text, checkboxes, images, etc., and I need all of them.

Comment: In another discussion about this problem, it occurred to me that this radio button input is the only one set by Javascript, AND the only one where the group of radios is inside a jQuery Dialog. (code not shown) I still don't have a solution, but the problem may be that IE8 -> 11 grabs data out of Dialogs differently than Firefox or Chrome. Note that I have the form attribute in the radio input statement, but that may not be enough for IE.

Answer (score 0):

From another conversation, I discovered that IE 11 does not support the form attribute in input statements. Case closed. I thought that by 11, IE would support that HTML5, but no - not yet.

Here's a link to a test page, if someone in the future needs to test whether IE supports the form attribute in an input statement.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/html5-form-attribute/